# Render objects from two queries in single for loop in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-templates, jinja2

I am trying to fetch objects from two different queries by using select_related() in order to get all of the related objects.

In template, I am using For loop in order to render all objects of first model separately, as separate containers of the data.

Inside each of these rendered objects of the first model, I need to show the corresponding data from both queries for the related second model.

The issue is that, when I am using For loop in template, I can only get the objects for the first related query, but not for the second query which is also related to the first model (basically, what second query is doing is getting all of the objects based on date less then today.)

Here is the code:

```
# IN THE MODELS

class BillType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Bill(models.Model):
    bill_type = models.ForeignKey(BillType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='billtype')
    month = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    recurring = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.month
```

```
# IN THE VIEW

# This will get all of the Bill Types needed for For Loop in the template
bill_types = BillType.objects.all()

# This will get all of the Bills related to the Bill Types. I will need this for showing the  
# corresponding Latest Bill in the template, beside the Overdue bill for each the Bill Types
bills = Bill.objects.select_related('bill_type').all()

# This need to get all of the Bills that are older than 'today'
today = datetime.today()
overdue = Bill.objects.select_related('bill_type').filter(due_date__lte=today).values()
```

```
# IN THE TEMPLATE

# This should loop through Bill Types and render separate <div> containers for each of the existing Bill Types
# I.e there would be two Bill Types such as Electricity and Water. This code should generate two separate containers
# that will show the corresponding Overdue bills for each of these Bill Types.

{% for bt in bill_types %}  

...

<div class="bo-widget-bill-cont overdue">
<span class="bo-overdue-warning"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
  <div class="bo-bill-info">

  # And in the lines below, I will need to Show the Overdue data, related to the bt or bill_types.

  <span>{{ bt.overdue.last.month }}</span>
    <div>
      <span>{{ bt.billtype.overdue.last.amount }}</span> 
      <p>Due Date:{{ overdue.last.due_date }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bo-bill-actions">
    <a class="bo-bill-paid-action" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

...


{% endfor %}
```

Any hint will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i think i couldn't get your question. do you want to display overdue amount of each bill type?

Comment: Yes. In the template, there will be rendered two separate containers (separate <div> elements) for each Bill Type. I.e. Electricity and Water bills. That's what the current for loop is doing. In the same loop, for each of these containers separately, I need to show the latest bill (which is working fine so far) and the last overdue bill corresponding to that container of that bill type.

Comment: can u plzz give me an example?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what kind of example exactly do you mean? I have provided all of the code from models, view and template (with comments included inside the code example) above and I think I've explained clearly what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: you have {{ bt.overdue.last.month }} in your template. But your BillType model donot have such fields ie overdue....

Comment: Yes, that's only one of few (unsuccessful) attempts to get the last month from overdue query, related to the 'bt' (the bill type object received through the for loop). What would be your solution?